# How are quotation marks used in this dotfile?

Tags: vimscript, comments

I'm a complete Linux beginner, trying to understand dotfiles. I've got the `.vimrc` dotfile, and tried to add the following command to the bottom:

```
" <Ctrl-l> redraws the screen and removes any search highlighting.
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohl<CR><C-l>
```

When I run `source .vimrc`, I get the `Unmatched ".` error. I assumed that this meant I had to put a fullstop at the end of a double quotation mark. But when I delete the command I've added in, I still get the error - it's a problem with the dotfile I've got.

So my problem is that I don't know how to fix the dotfile, and I don't understand what the `"` is doing in the dotfile in the first place. I've Googled and searched on SO but not found any answers. It seems like it's being used to mark a comment - but I thought that `#` was used to mark comments.

What is " being used for in this dotfile, and how can I fix it so that it runs properly?

Here's the dotfile:

```
" main
syntax enable
set encoding=utf-8
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set smarttab
set number
set showcmd
set bs=2                                        " use backspace in INSERT mode
"set nomodeline                                  " turn off modeline parsing
set cursorline
set autoindent
filetype indent on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
set wildmenu                                    " autocomplete menu
set lazyredraw                                  " redraw only when necessary
set showmatch                                   " highlight matching parentheses
set smartcase
set incsearch                                   " search as char entered
set hlsearch                                    " highlight search matches
nnoremap #<space> :nohlsearch<CR>               " #<space> turn off search hl
set foldenable                                  " enable folding
set foldlevelstart=10                           " open most folds be default
set foldnestmax=10                              " 10 nested fold max
nnoremap <space> za                             " space open/closes fold
set foldmethod=indent                           " fold based on indent level
nnoremap j gj                                   " move down visually
nnoremap k gk                                   " move up visually
nnoremap gV `[v`]                               " highlight latest - ins mode


" status line that shows more information than the default one
" set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\ [FMT=%{&ff}]\ [T=%Y]\ [HEX=\%02.2B]\ [POS=%04l,%04v\ (%p%%)]\ [lines=%L]
" set laststatus=2

" split
set splitbelow
set splitright

" split nav
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Welcome! *"When I run `source .vimrc`, I get the `Unmatched ".` error."* Looks to me that you're trying to source it in bash and not in Vim... Is that the case? If so, what you actually need instead is the `:source` command inside of Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per filbranden's comment, make sure `:source .vimrc` is a vim command! You don't run `.vimrc` from a shell (like bash), which will require balanced quotes in scripts.

---

The first thing to know is that this particular dotfile, the `.vimrc`, is used to configure vim.

The second thing to know is that vim has one of the most comprehensive help systems I've ever seen: type `:help` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get started.

The third thing to know is that all of vimscript is Ex-commands (also called colon-commands). They are usually documented as `:help :somecommand`.

---

With that out of the way, the `.vimrc` contains vimscript, so we can check `:help :"`, which gets us to `:help :quote`:

```
'"' at the start of a line causes the whole line to be ignored.  '"'
after a command causes the rest of the line to be ignored.  This can be used
to add comments.  Example: >
    :set ai     "set 'autoindent' option
It is not possible to add a comment to a shell command ":!cmd" or to the
":map" command and a few others (mainly commands that expect expressions)
that see the '"' as part of their argument:
```

So the `"` is a comment in vimscript.

But we also note that we can't have comments after the map command! This is also seen in `:help map-comments`:

```
It is not possible to put a comment after these commands, because the '"'
character is considered to be part of the {lhs} or {rhs}. However, one can
use |", since this starts a new, empty command with a comment.
```

---

So now we know what the error is: several `nnoremap` commands have comments after them; but, they can't, due to the way `map` works. General best practice is to put the comments on a line before the map:

```
" space opens/closes fold
nnoremap <space> za
```

---

As a complete aside: learning to customize vim is a fantastic journey (and welcome to it!). Most experts recommend not copying wholesale other's config; it tends to help your learning more to understand what's being done (e.g., by reading `:help`) and proceeding with a mix of (a) writing the code you need and (b) copying the bits from others that you like/need.

Comment: This is all useful and correct, but I don't _think_ it explains the behaviour the OP is seeing. As you've explained, the problem with trying to put a comment at the end of a map is that the characters are instead included in the `rhs`, but the OP is actually seeing an error message.

Comment: @Rich you may be right, I just saw fil’s comment and am wondering myself.